# How can I avoid Same Origin Policy exception when using AWS API Gateway and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a SPA (fronted by CloundFront) which calls a GET endpoint which I have set up on APIGateway. Domain of the spa is different than the domain of API Gateway. Am getting Same Origin policy exceptions like below when I my SPA tries to do a GET on a resource

```
 "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on requested resource"
```

Here is my setup on API Gateway. I have an Options resource which returns the following

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'GET, OPTIONS'
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With'
Access-Control-Origin: '*'
```

I have a Get Resource, which in turn calls my backend service (proxies to my service). I have setup the resource to return these headers as part of the response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Browser's Options call returns in a 200, with all the necessary Access Control Stuff. But when the browser makes the GET call, I get the same origin policy exception. Any ideas whats happening here? Is it because my GET response does not explicitly set a value for Access-Control-Origin?

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an Options resource which returns the following

The header you need is Access-Control-*Allow*-Origin: '*'.

But, yes, you do need to return it, because a simple `GET` doesn't do a pre-flight `OPTIONS *`.

Comment: How do I add this in API Gateway? My GET Resource just the request to my backend and returns the response from my backend as is. I dont see a way to modify outgoing response headers in API Gateway

Comment: Your answer is correct in that I do have to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with a value of *.  For others who have ran into the same issue when using AWS API Gateway - If you are using API Gateway to proxy to your backend service, you will not be able to modify the responses that comes back from your api. "Integeration Responses" will be greyed out. If on the other hand, you choose not to proxy, you are allowed to modify the responses from your api